# Saving NSManagedObject property of an NSManagedObject object type

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject

I have an NSManagedObject called Package. This package has multiple objects called Item, which also is NSManagedObject. So package-item relationship is one-to-many(Package has a property of type Item).

The thing is that when I save(encode) the Package the Item it doesn't save.Can I encode a NSManagedObject of another NSManagedObject? I looked over the internet but I didn't find an answer.

Comment: Please show how exactly are you saving your changes and what do you mean by encoding here?. You should save the context (NSManagedObjectContext) and once it is done, all the entities in that context are saved.

Comment: Yes, I save the context.  [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion

Comment: Please provide some code of how you create new Items and how you add them to Package.